# pythonic way to make sure data is always decreasing within group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
Id date     value
x1 01-01-22  46
x1 02-01-22  46
x1 03-01-22  45.8
....
x2 03-04-22  57
X2 03-04-22  62
....
```

The number in `value` should always decrease (or the stay the same) as time goes on. So the next observation for x2 would fail.

What's the most pythonic way to append a column of 1's and 0's if the value increases by say more than 3% (as there could be some measurement error).  In R, I would just use dplyr & groupby and I was hoping for something as elegant in pandas.

*Edit for clarity*: The decrease must be within the id (eg per item).

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do it (edited I had the minus flipped) (edited again after clarification)

```
def f(gdf):
    return ((gdf.value - gdf.value.shift())/gdf.value.shift()) > .03
df['flag'] = df.groupby('Id').apply(f).values
```

Comment: nice! to map to 0/1: `(((df.value - df.value.shift())/df.value.shift()) > .03).astype(int)`

Comment: It's close but might have an error when the id flips to the next one? I'll make that more explicit so I think there needs to be a group by

Comment: Ahhh. I see what you are saying.   Let me rework it.

Comment: See if my edits are what you needed

Answer (score 2):

You have `pct_change`:

```
df['big_change'] = df.groupby('Id')['value'].pct_change().gt(.03).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   Id      date  value  big_change
0  x1  01-01-22   46.0           0
1  x1  02-01-22   46.0           0
2  x1  03-01-22   45.8           0
3  x2  03-04-22   57.0           0
4  x2  03-04-22   62.0           1
```

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about that method